# サブディレクトリ内のファイル内の文字列を一括置換したい

Tags: zsh, sed

検索するとやり方の書かれた記事がたくさん出てくるんですが
sed が gnu 版かどうかで２パターンあって
どっちを実行してもうまくいきません

```
sed --version
gsed (GNU sed) 4.8
```

となるので sed は gnu 版みたいなんですが

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i '' 's/置換前/置換後/g'
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/置換前/置換後/g'
sed: 1: "./vars/front.yml": invalid command code .
```

となってしまいます

何が悪いんでしょうか

**実行環境**

MAC OS
zsh
gnu sed を gsed というバイナリ名でインストールして
alias で sed という名前にしています

Comment: エラーメッセージの内容から察するに、`xargs sed -i's/置換前/置換後/g'` としている可能性があります(`-i` オプションと `s` コマンドの間にスペースがない)。

Comment: いただいた回答からコピーしてターミナルにはりつけても同様でした

Comment: 「alias で sed という名前にしています」との事ですが、xargs の内部では `exec(3)` 類を使用してコマンドを実行します。つまり、alias による展開(`sed` -> `gsed`)が行われず、OSX 本来の BSD sed を実行しているのではないかと思われます。なので、`xargs gsed -i 's/置換前/置換後/g'` とすべきではないかと。

Comment: その通りでした！　alias の理解が足りてませんでした

Answer (score 0):

まず、sed の -i オプションは間違いではないですか？

`find . -type f | xargs sed 's/置換前/置換後/g'`
は問題ないと思います。

`RE error: illegal byte sequence` は、置換前か置換後の正規表現（RE=Regular Expression）に誤りがあるのではないかと思います。

Comment: -i はファイルをそのまま置き換えるという意味で使いました。-i なしで実行(回答からコピー)すると標準出力にファイルの中身がはかれるんですが途中で 'sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence' になってしまいます

Answer (score 0):

```
LANG=C find . -type f | xargs sed -i '' 's/置換前/置換後/g'
```

ではいかがでしょうか？`sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`が出るのは文字コード違いのせいかもしれません。

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/置換前/置換後/g'
sed: 1: "./vars/front.yml": invalid command code .
```

はsedのiオプションがSUFFIXを要求しているものと思われます。

---

こちらの環境では以下で問題なく置換できました。

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/置換前/置換後/g'
```

環境

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
パッケージ作成者: Debian
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

作者 Jay Fenlason、 Tom Lord、 Ken Pizzini、
Paolo Bonzini、 Jim Meyering、および Assaf Gordon。
GNU sed home page: <https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <https://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
```

Comment: LANG=Cをつけたものを回答から完全にコピー貼り付けして実行したんですが同じエラーになります。MAC OS に gnu sed をいれてしまってるのがまずいんでしょうか